# Error: missing \begin{document} in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have error in my LaTeX document, when run my file, have a error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

and this tag `\begin{document}` exists in my code

```
\documentclass[12pt‎, ‎a4paper]{article}‎
\usepackage{graphicx}  % inserting images
\usepackage[top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}                 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{color, pdfcolmk}
%\usepackage{sweave}
% setting the margins of page
\usepackage{xepersian}

\usepackage{setspace}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{XB Zar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Zar}
\setdigitfont{XB Zar}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\SepMark{-}
 \DefaultMathsDigits 
%-----------------------list-------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{فهرست شکل ها} 
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{فهرست جدول‌ها} 

\renewcommand{\refname}{\rl{{مرجع‌ها}\hfill}}
%---------------------end list-------------------------------------

%\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{left=35mm,right=35mm,  top=30mm,bottom=30mm}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Where is the `\end{document}`? I don't see it in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy the code you have shown here into Notepad++ with UTF-8 input encoding, I get the following result for the first line:

```
\documentclass[12pt?, ?a4paper]{article}?
```

From that I assume that you have non-UTF-8 characters which aren't recognized by LaTeX and thus it throws an error. Try to replace that line by

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
```

As @nowox remarked in a comment, the `\end{document}` is missing. Make sure that you have that in your file.

Comment: The character is the unicode character [left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark), `0x200e`.

Comment: tanx for your answer, I forgot to copy all my code in here . \end{document} has been in my code :)