# how do you change colors of certain cells in xtable markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have a data frame called j:

```
dput(j)

structure(list(Trans = c(89.8, 3337, NA, 97.55, NA, 3558.7, NA, 
4290.6, NA, 65.95, 94.55, 3495.9), `%CPU` = c(6.938, 79.853, 
1.875, 4.87, 1.46, 37.885, 1.63, 64.576, 1.165, 3.425, 5.67, 
33.856), `%Heap Used` = c(9.9, 76.95, 3.77, 9.8, 6.73, 59.23, 
3.94, 67.38, 3.73, 9.13, 9.57, 62.11), `Heap Usage/MB` = c(263.884, 
1942.246, 99.104, 257.717, 178.951, 1657.447, 99.933, 2137.134, 
96.687, 242.024, 256.302, 1646.117)), .Names = c("Trans", "%CPU", 
"%Heap Used", "Heap Usage/MB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

If I want to color code a cell based on threshold in r markdown, how would I do that?

For example if %CPU>70, I need to color code that cell to be red.

I can print it in r markdown like this:

```
print(xtable(j_cor,digits=2,row.names=FALSE,caption="JVM Usage"),caption.placement="top", tabular.environment="longtable",comment=FALSE,floating=FALSE)
```

But I like to place colors in the cells based on threshold r markdown Any ideas?

I have tried something like this, but the color or the cell did not change in pdf file:

```
j[,2] = ifelse(j[,2] < 60, paste0("\\colorbox{red}{", j[,2], "}"), j[,2])


sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggthemes_3.4.0    flexclust_1.3-4   modeltools_0.2-21 lattice_0.20-35   tidyr_0.6.1       jsonlite_1.4      Rcpp_0.12.10      lazyeval_0.2.0   
 [9] knitr_1.16        gridExtra_2.0.0   xtable_1.8-0      data.table_1.9.6  cowplot_0.6.2     reshape2_1.4.1    corrplot_0.77     scales_0.4.1     
[17] stringr_1.0.0     chron_2.3-47      ggplot2_2.2.1     dplyr_0.5.0       purrr_0.2.2       xml2_1.0.0        plyr_1.8.4        RCurl_1.95-4.7   
[25] bitops_1.0-6      XML_3.98-1.3      httr_1.0.0        rmarkdown_1.5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tools_3.2.4      digest_0.6.12    evaluate_0.10    tibble_1.3.0     gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.6-1        parallel_3.2.4   yaml_2.1.14     
 [9] rprojroot_1.2    R6_2.2.1         magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.0  htmltools_0.3.5  assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2 labeling_0.3    
[17] stringi_1.1.5    munsell_0.4.3
```

I have copied the exact text to my Rstudio and tried to run it, I am getting this error:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test_color.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test_color.pdf --template "C:\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 <

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test_color.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test_color.pdf --template "C:\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
```

Comment: @user20650, when I include , sanitize.text.function = identity, I get this error: pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted

Comment: Did you try just running the answer at the link without changing anything - I just reran it without issue.

Comment: yes, I get this error: output file: test.knit.md

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:

Comment: I cant reproduce but several tex questions on this, and maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794157/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-in-rstudio

Comment: where do you change this line: --latex-engine=xelatex

Comment: from the example from the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895829/how-can-xtable-do-cell-coloring/40897036#40897036) the `output:` is specified at the start. Just amend this with the code from [the second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794157/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-in-rstudio?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: ok, I've put there then now it is saying \begin{document} section is missing. I am using knitr and rmarkdown to generate pdf. I am confused, this is not working. when I take out "sanitize.text.function = identity", from the print(xtable) it works.

Comment: What code are you using to output the pdf: ? `rmarkdown::render("so_ex.Rmd")` ?

Comment: I get this error: output file: test.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 <

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code from the other answer or did you retype the code. Some tex questions/answers suggest some end of line or extra characters (that may not be visible in your text editor) can be introduced when copy/pasting - so maybe  try actually typing the commands in a new text file.. ps can you add the results of `seesionInfo()` to your question in case its relevant please.

Comment: maybe relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82818/latex-error-missing-begindocument , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138631/latex-error-missing-begin-document , http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-missbegdoc.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543113/error-missing-begindocument-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the `%` signs in the column names.  You'll need to specify sanitizing functions for text, to deal with the LaTeX commands, and for column names to handle the percent signs.

Use the `\cellcolor` command to color a cell in LaTeX table.

Here is an example .Rmd file

````
---
title: "Colors of xtable cells"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{longtable}
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
output:
    pdf_document
---

Build the example data set

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(xtable)
j <-
  structure(list(Trans = c(89.8, 3337, NA, 97.55, NA, 3558.7, NA, 
  4290.6, NA, 65.95, 94.55, 3495.9), `%CPU` = c(6.938, 79.853, 
  1.875, 4.87, 1.46, 37.885, 1.63, 64.576, 1.165, 3.425, 5.67, 
  33.856), `%Heap Used` = c(9.9, 76.95, 3.77, 9.8, 6.73, 59.23, 
  3.94, 67.38, 3.73, 9.13, 9.57, 62.11), `Heap Usage/MB` = c(263.884, 
  1942.246, 99.104, 257.717, 178.951, 1657.447, 99.933, 2137.134, 
  96.687, 242.024, 256.302, 1646.117)), .Names = c("Trans", "%CPU", 
  "%Heap Used", "Heap Usage/MB"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -12L))
```

Create a version of the `data.frame` with red cells for \%CPU greater than 70.
Set the color and round to two digits.

```{r, include = FALSE}
j[, 2] <- ifelse(j[, 2] > 70, paste("\\cellcolor{red}{", round(j[, 2], 2), "}"), round(j[, 2], 2))
```

The resulting table is:

```{r results = "asis"}
print(xtable(j,
             digits = 2,
             row.names = FALSE,
             caption = "JVM Usage"),
      sanitize.text.function = identity,
      sanitize.colnames.function = NULL,
      caption.placement   = "top",
      tabular.environment = "longtable",
      comment = FALSE,
      floating=FALSE) 
```
````

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: output file: test_color.knit.md
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:_

Comment: I have updated the post with the error, I am getting now with your exact post.

Comment: I get this error: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Comment: These lines at the top are causing the issue, coloring the cells. Any ideas how I could address this:    - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}

Comment: Have you tried adding `- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the `header-includes:` section?

Comment: I now get this error: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.159   2 & 3337.00 & \cellcolor

Comment: Hi Peter, looks like I am making a progress. I've changed cellcolor to just color, I do see the text color changing now. Is it possible to that it is not cellcolor, something else as key word?

Comment: \\cellcolor does not work. Do I need a special package/library for the cellcolor to work?

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Comment: no luck. I still get this error: "! Undefined control sequence.l.155 1 & A & \cellcolor"

Comment: can you edit your question, or post a new one, to show what is in your yaml header?

Comment: can you please take a look at this. I've tried every suggestions, still getting the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311909/how-do-you-color-the-cell-in-rmarkdown-pdf-output?noredirect=1#comment77587162_45311909