# unable to change the colors of the xtable cells in rmarkdown output to pdf

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr

I have this r markdown code:

````
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
output:
    pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex

---



```{r, results="asis"}

library(xtable)
library(formattable)
# Your data
tab = data.frame(category = c("A","B","C"), groupA = c(.2,.3,.5), groupB= c(.6,.7,.9))

# Function to cut your data, and assign colour to each range
f <- function(x) cut(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, Inf), 
                      labels=c("green", "red", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "brown", "white"),
                      include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE)

# Apply function to columns: this overwrites your data
tab[c("groupA", "groupB")] <- lapply(tab[c("groupA", "groupB")], function(x)
                                            paste0("\\cellcolor{", f(x), "}", x))
# Sanitise output 
print(xtable(tab), sanitize.text.function = identity)
```
````

I need to color code the cells of the table.

I am getting this error:

```
output file: test.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 <

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.pdf --template "C:\Users\e598140\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

Any ideas what is the issue here?

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: any ideas what I may be missing here?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Rmarkdown?

Comment: running rmarkdown_1.5

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: Just remove `: latex_engine: xelatex` after `pdf_document` and it will use pdflatex instead.

Comment: @HubertL, that's what I had originally, not working either.

Comment: Any ideas what I am missing here? I really need the colors working on the table.

Comment: @user1471980 ; did you read / try anything suggested at the links in the comments at your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335165/how-do-you-change-colors-of-certain-cells-in-xtable-markdown#comment75841332_44335165 . It would definitely help if you added the details of what you tried, and what didnt work to your question to save people offering repeat suggestions.

Comment: It works fine for me.  Suggestion:  1.  Make sure you can build a simple file, e.g. the default one from "File | New file | R Markdown | PDF".  If that works, then add stuff to it from the bad one until the problem appears.  If not, then the problem is with your RStudio/LaTeX setup.

Comment: @user2554330, it works until I need to color code the cells in table. Then it stops working.

Comment: @user1471980, which line does that?

Comment: @user2554330 print(xtable(tab), sanitize.text.function = identity)

Comment: I don't see anything about colors in that line.

Comment: @user2554330, if I add this code to top: "header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}", it gives me error. When I take it out, it produceses, the pdf file. It looks like it has something to do with the color. Any ideas?

Comment: That makes no sense.  Without that line, you should get an error because the `\cellcolor` macro would not be defined.  (In a file exactly like the current version of your main example, I get no errors.)

Comment: @user2554330 this is what I see in print(xtable) output: \cellcolor{red}{4.4535}, no color codes