# how do you color the cell in rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I cannot get cellcolor to work in rmarkdown:

````
---
header-includes:
   -  \usepackage{colortbl} 
   -  \usepackage{color} 

output:
    pdf_document
---

```{r, results="asis"}

library(xtable)
# Your data
tab = data.frame(category = c("A","B","C"), groupA = c(.2,.3,.5), groupB= c(.6,.7,.9))

# Function to cut your data, and assign colour to each range
f <- function(x) cut(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, Inf), 
                      labels=c("green", "red", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "brown", "white"),
                      include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE)

# Apply function to columns: this overwrites your data
tab[c("groupA", "groupB")] <- lapply(tab[c("groupA", "groupB")], function(x)
                                            paste0("\\cellcolor{", f(x), "}", x))
# Sanitise output 
print(xtable(tab), sanitize.text.function = identity)
```
````

I keep getting this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.155 1 & A & \cellcolor
```

Any ideas what does cellcolor needs to work?

Comment: is this the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373073/unable-to-change-the-colors-of-the-xtable-cells-in-rmarkdown-output-to-pdf

Comment: If I use `xcolor` instead of `color` I'm able to compile the document without error via `rmarkdown::render`.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

The OP's example works for me when including `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` instead. For another approach see below.

### Alternative Approach

*Here is another approach using the very handy `condformat` package. This way you don't have to include any TeX packages by hand and don't have to worry about escaping special characters etc.*

---

We basically create a `condformat_tbl` object and add two formatting rules for each column.

````
---
output:
    pdf_document
---

```{r, include = F}
library(condformat)
cols        <- c('green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 
                 'yellow', 'purple', 'brown', 'white')
names(cols) <- cols # important for the colours arg in rule_fill_discrete
                    # since it matches the result of 'expression' with the names of the 'colours' vector

f   <- function(x) cut(x, c(0, seq(.2, .8, .1), Inf), labels = cols,
                       include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE)
tab <- data.frame(category = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                  groupA = c(.2, .3, .5), 
                  groupB = c(.6, .7, .9))
```


```{r, results = 'asis', echo = F}
condformat(tab) + 
  rule_fill_discrete(groupA, expression = f(groupA), colours = cols) +
  rule_fill_discrete(groupB, expression = f(groupB), colours = cols) 
```
````

Notice, that the value for the colours argument in `rule_fill_discrete` is vector of key-value pairs. The keys are the possible results of the expression.

And this is what you get:

[image]

Comment: I still see this error:! Undefined control sequence.
l.91 A & \cellcolor

Comment: Try `devtools::install_github('zeehio/condformat')`

Comment: I did install the package using install.packages("condformat")

Comment: All I can add is that its working with `RStudio 1.0.143`, `R  3.4.1 `, `condformat 0.6.0.9000` and `knitr 1.16`

Comment: @user1471980 ; given your difficulty in rendering this, and similar issues on your previous questions,  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335165/how-do-you-change-colors-of-certain-cells-in-xtable-markdown#comment75841332_44335165), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373073/unable-to-change-the-colors-of-the-xtable-cells-in-rmarkdown-output-to-pdf) , this may be something local to your script / tex install, rather than R, and so may benefit from asking at the tex site. (if you do,  I would link to each of your questions so all comments can be seen)

Comment: Looks like a nice solution and works interactively, but cannot knit this to PDF either. If I hit "knit" in RStudio, it fails with "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> structure -> condformat2latex -> colnames<-". OTOH, `knit()` successfully produces a MD file. But `knit2pdf` fails with "! Emergency stop
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)". Weird …

Comment: @CL Try the developer version of condformat if you haven't done it already.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Indeed, that solves the problem. (At least for the "knit" button in RStudio and `rmarkdown::render`. Not for `knit2pdf` though, but who cares …). I'd upvote but for "some reason" I cannot do that (again). ;-)